# Webscraping Using Scrapy webpage doesn't fully load

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Trying to scrape a website with restaurants information.

page does not seem to be fully loaded with missing content.

Tried different tools like selenium and BeautifulSoup, same issue.

process so far.

SCRAPY:

```
fetch('https://www.talabat.com/egypt/restaurant/643637/dominos-pizza-kafr-abdo?aid=7123')
response.css('div.accordionstyle__AccordionContainer-h3jkuk-0 gnYKPd')
[]
```

Beautiful Soup:

```
r = requests.get(f'https://www.talabat.com/egypt/restaurant/643637/dominos-pizza-kafr-abdo?aid=7123')
soup = bs(r.content)


resturant_cats = soup.find(class_='mt-2')
resturant_items = soup.find_all(class_='content open')
resturantmenu = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ItemName','ItemCat','ItemPrice','ItemDesc'],index = range(len(resturant_items)))
# resturant_cats[1].find(class_='f-15').get_text()

print(resturant_items)
```

They Both return missing the target data.

Upon further inspection, the loaded source returns this HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-11">
              <div class="menu-searchstyles__MenuSearchContainer-sc-383aw2-0 hHaWx">
               <input class="w-100 pl-2 py-2 pr-6 muted mb-3" placeholder="Search menu item" type="text" value=""/>
               <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16 fa-2x search-fa f-18" data-icon="search" data-prefix="fas" focusable="false" role="img" viewbox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z" fill="currentColor">
                </path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = json.loads(soup.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(goal['props']['pageProps']
                      ['initialMenuState']['menuData']['items'])
    print(df)


main('https://www.talabat.com/egypt/restaurant/643637/dominos-pizza-kafr-abdo?aid=7123')
```

Output:

```
           id                           name  ... isItemDiscount  isWithImage
0   770227845                     Meal for 4  ...          False        False
1   770227846                     Meal for 6  ...          False        False
2   770227847                 Barbecue Feast  ...          False        False
3   770227848                   Deluxe Feast  ...          False        False
4   770227849                     Margherita  ...          False        False
..        ...                            ...  ...            ...          ...
81  770227928                    RANCH SAUCE  ...          False        False
82  770227929                    Sugar Glaze  ...          False        False
83  770227932            Cinna Stix 8 Pieces  ...          False        False
84  770227933  Pineapple Cinna Stix 8 Pieces  ...          False        False
85  770227934         Chocolate Lava Souffle  ...          False        False

[86 rows x 14 columns]
```

Comment: That is extremely helpful and right to the point, may I ask for an explanation as to why it didn't load properly?

Comment: @OmarAhmed The website is loaded dynamically via JS, `requests` library will not render the JS for you! you can use selenium for such case by waiting for element to be presented, otherwise you can use my solution

Comment: Also I do receive an error of 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

on goal = json.loads(soup.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text)

and my soup returns empty string

soup.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text

Comment: @OmarAhmed did you made any changes to the code ? as it's run from my side perfectly !

Comment: here is the exact code error https://imgur.com/a/VDDqTsq

Comment: I actually did try Selenium yet ran into the same issue where a section of the page doesn't load at all

Comment: @OmarAhmed what's the response code on your end ?

Comment: a sample of the soup returned https://imgur.com/a/c2XDmBW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240658/discussion-between--c-and-omar-ahmed).